Gmail changes id of element
I am working on some HTML Email templates and noticed, that Gmail is changing id attributes. How can I prevent it from happening?
This is how it is supposed to be, the id of the h2 is "aOverview"

This is what Gmail makes of it, the id of the h2 is changed to "m_4802664025727067780aOverview"

Because of that change that Gmail does, the link going back to this anchor does not work.
